# Подсчёт обращений к php файлу через ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Всем доброго времени суток. подскажите кто может, как можно подсчитать количество обращений к php файлу через ajax ? 
Имеются 2 страницы - 01.html и 02.php 
Из первой страницы через ajax отправляется post запрос на страницу 02.php и возвращается какой то результат.Как можно подсчитать количество обращений к скрипту php ?

```
01.html

$('#two td').click(function () {
 var ful2=$(this).html();
  $.post('/02.php',{two:ful2},function (data) {
  $('.otvet2').html(data);
});
```

```
02.php

$one=Input::get('one');
$two=Input::get('two');

if(!empty($one))
   return $one;
elseif(!empty($two))
   return $two;
else
   echo "empty";
```

Comment: От всех пользователей или от одного? Если одного то через сессию. Если всех через знчение которое храниться где-то ( текстовый файл, база данных, память(apc, memcache))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем собственно проблема?

Выставите ограничение на выполнение кода только в режиме xmlhttprequest (AJAX):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    ... // здесь код счетчика
}
```

Подсчет может вестись в базу данных или в файл.

P.S. На будущее рекомендую любой асинхронный код выполнять в отдельном файле с оберткой xmlhttprequest.